# Can you only use one Select command w/SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

This is a pretty simple question that I haven't been able to find an answer for. Is it possible to have two separate SELECT commands (from the same table) in the same SqlDataSource command to populate two different cells in a given GridView?

I haven't been able to find current information so far.

::EDIT::

The challenge is that I'm attempting to manupulate one cell with a COUNT command and the second cell with a numerical grand total from the same information.

Comment: I can't seem to think of a situation where you couldn't find the data you needed in one SELECT query from 1 table. You can select columns, you can use OR and AND to make multiple clauses. If you need 2 cells, you can get 2 cells with one SELECT query.

Comment: The challenge is that I'm manipulating one cell with a COUNT command and the second cell is a numerical grand total.

Comment: No, it's not possible. But we can get away with it in different ways. Can you post your sql queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Combine results from two separate SELECT Statements by doing something like this..

```
SELECT X.A , Y.B
FROM (SELECT Column1 AS A FROM TableName) X, (SELECT Column2 AS B FROM TableName) Y
```